# Customize Wordpress date archive widget for categories

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to modify the Wordpress theme's date archive widget to use it for every category.
With the following code it's possible to show only posts of an specific category, but I have to paste the `categories_id` as a fixed value. I want to do it dynamically.

I've tried to retrieve the `category_id` by using `get_queried_object()`, but it doesn't seem to work.

What is wrong with the code?

```
function wpse75668_filter_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

$page_object = get_queried_object();
$idObj = get_category_by_slug("'".$page_object->cat_name."'"); 
$id = $idObj->term_id;  

if ( $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() ) {
    // Only modify date-based archives
    if ( is_date() ) {
        // Only display posts from category ID 
        $query->set( 'cat', "'".$id."'" );
    }
}
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse75668_filter_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: Without actually testing, remove the all the quote marks in the `get_category_by_slug( $page_object->cat_name )` and `$query->set( 'cat', $id )`. You don't need those.

Comment: It's still not working properly

Comment: As I said, this wasn't necessarily a fix for your issue, but you don't need those. Also, not working really doesn't help us. You said you are trying to modify the `date archive widget`, yet you are modifying the main query.

Comment: The date archive widget is inside my Category-Template. If someone is clicking a link like: "June 2018", it should redirect the user to the date-archive-page, which is showing only posts from that category.